# Loading view and routing in CodeIgniter after user logging in

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to make a login with CI which basically after the user is logged in, where he'll be redirected to either page `admin/dashboard` or `superadmin/dashboard` depending on their user type role. I've successfully loaded the views but there's something wrong with the url. After logging in, the website manages to load the right view depending on the user's type, but the url still says .../auth/login. How do I change this? I want the url to say `.../admin/dashboard` or `.../superadmin/dashboard`

This is what I've got in my controller Auth function login.

```
if($this->ion_auth->is_admin()){
    $this->load->view('superadmin/dashboard_view');
}else if($this->ion_auth->in_group('members')){
    $this->load->view('admin/dashboard_view');
}else{
    redirect('/', 'refresh');
}
```

And here's my login form.

```html
 <?php echo form_open("auth/login");?>

          <p>
            <?php echo lang('login_identity_label', 'identity');?>
            <?php echo form_input($identity);?>
          </p>

          <p>
            <?php echo lang('login_password_label', 'password');?>
            <?php echo form_input($password);?>
          </p>

          <p>
            <?php echo lang('login_remember_label', 'remember');?>
            <?php echo form_checkbox('remember', '1', FALSE, 'id="remember"');?>
          </p>

          <p><?php echo form_submit('submit', lang('login_submit_btn'));?></p>

   <?php echo form_close();?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of loading views from the login you will need to redirect. This means two different controllers, one for admin

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller
{
    public function dashboard()
    {
     $this->load->view('admin/dashboard_view');
    }
}
```

And another for superadmin

```
class Superadmin extends CI_Controller
{
    public function dashboard()
    {
     $this->load->view('superadmin/dashboard_view');
    }
}
```

And controller Auth function login

```
if($this->ion_auth->is_admin()){
    redirect('superadmin/dashboard');
}else if($this->ion_auth->in_group('members')){
    redirect('admin/dashboard');
}else{
    redirect('/', 'refresh');
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Anyway, do we always have to use redirect in the Auth controller? I don't mind with that, just wondering why.